# Retrieving data from SQL Server with R using query with MAXDOP option

Tags: r, sql-server, rodbc

I am using R and the RODBC library to execute queries on a SQL Server database. This works fine and returns desired result sets when I execute a single select statement, or even [create multiple temporary tables before selecting my final dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747768/rodbc-temporary-table-issue-when-connecting-to-ms-sql-server).

However, when I insert the option

```
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

after my queries (which my platform administrator has asked that I use after all queries) I get the error

> [RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect

Is there anything I can do to resolve this error while still adhering to the requirement that queries not use parallel processing?

Comment: Why do you want the queries to not go parallel? Let SQL Server decide what should and shouldn't go parallel.

Comment: @M.Ali I have no issue letting SQL Server decide, but my platform administrator has asked that I not let queries run in parallel; something to do with conserving resources or something. I'm just trying to comply with my administrator.